# Using Hash.new as an initial value when reducing an array

Tags: ruby, hash, reduce

I have an array like so

```
[1,1,2,3,3,3,4,5,5]
```

and I want to count the number of occurrences of each number, which I'm trying to do like so

```
[1,1,2,3,3,3,4,5,5].reduce(Hash.new(0)) { |hash,number| hash[number] += 1 }
```

The problem is I get the following error when I try to run it

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `[]=' for 1:Fixnum
    from (irb):6:in `block in irb_binding'
    from (irb):6:in `each'
    from (irb):6:in `reduce'
    from (irb):6
```

Am I able to set the initial value like this, or am I getting this wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`each_with_object`](http://apidock.com/rails/Enumerable/each_with_object) for cleaner syntax

```
[1,1,2,3,3,3,4,5,5].each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |number, hash| hash[number] += 1 }
```

Note that order of arguments is reverse i.e. `|number, hash|`

Comment: I always forget that there is `each_with_object`. I find it cleaner than returning the hash in every iteration.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `reduce`, but if you want so, you have to return the hash again:

```
[1,1,2,3,3,3,4,5,5].reduce(Hash.new(0)) do |hash,number|
  hash[number] += 1 
  hash
end
```

Without that the value of `hash[number]` would be returned. The value of a hash assignment is the value itself. The block builds on the value you have returned previously.

Which means, that after the first it would try something like this: `1[1] += 1`, which of course does not work, because Fixnums do not implement the method `[]=`.

Answer (score 5):

I like to use `reduce` with `hash.update`. It returns the array and I do not need the `; hash` part:

```
[1,1,2,3,3,3,4,5,5].reduce(Hash.new(0)) { |h, n| h.update(n => h[n].next) }
```

Comment: Nice!  I wasn't familiar with `update`.  Have tucked it away.  (Readers: note he could have used `+1` instead of `next`, if that's not obvious).

Answer (score 2):

Your question has been answered, but here's another way to skin the cat:

[Edited to adopt @David's suggestion.]

```
a = [1,1,2,3,3,3,4,5,5]
Hash[a.group_by(&:to_i).map {|g| [g.first, g.last.size]}]
```

This also works:

```
a.group_by{|e| e}.inject({}) {|h, (k,v)| h[k] = v.size; h}
```

and can be improved by adopting @spickermann's use of `update` (or it's synonym, `merge!`), to get rid of that irritating `; h` at the end:

```
a.group_by{|e| e}.inject({}) {|h, (k,v)| h.merge!(k => v.size)}
```

Formerly, I had:

```
Hash[*a.group_by(&:to_i).to_a.map {|g| [g.first, g.last.size]}.flatten]
```

I don't like `to_i` here.  I wanted to use `to_proc` instead of `...group_by {|x| x|}` (as used in one of the solutions above) and was looking for a method `m` that returns the receiver or its value. `to_i` was the best I could do (e.g., `2.to_i => 2`), but only for Integers.  Can anyone suggest a method that returns the receiver for a wide range of objects whose use with `to_proc` makes it's purpose obvious?

Comment: Overcomplicated ;) You may simplify your code to just `Hash[a.group_by(&:to_i).map {|g| [g.first, g.last.size]}]` at least. Hash inherits `map` from `Enumerable` so unnecessary to convert it to an `Array`. Also you may avoid flattening the resulting array and so the splat operator. Not to mention you can split object passed by `map` at block arguments. I'd agree Ruby lacks `.id` method returning itself (spoiled with Haskell ;))

Answer (score 1):

That's simple:

```
[1,1,2,3,3,3,4,5,5].group_by {|e| e}.collect {|k,v| [k,v.count]}
#=> [[1, 2], [2, 1], [3, 3], [4, 1], [5, 2]]
```

if result required in a Hash object

```
Hash[[1,1,2,3,3,3,4,5,5].group_by {|e| e}.collect {|k,v| [k,v.count]}]
#=> {1=>2, 2=>1, 3=>3, 4=>1, 5=>2}
```